# Need advice on how to optimize my function PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, xml-parsing

I need help/advice on optimizing my function. The function should look for attribute values in the table `REASON_ATTR_VALUE` by using the attribute names from the input XML file and generate the output XML file.
In the function from the input file, I transfer the data to collection `v_attrs_in` (containing reason identifiers and attribute names to be checked), check the data in the table `REASON_ATTR_VALUE`, and form another collection `v_attrs` (containing reason identifiers and attribute names and values). For this collection, I generate an output file.
Full text of function:

```sql
function get_reason_attr_value (p_reasons clob) return clob 
  is
    v_attrs reason_attrs;
    v_attrs_in reasons;
    v_reason_ids reason_id_list := reason_id_list();
    i pls_integer;
    v_xml_reasons_in xmltype;
    v_xml_reasons_out xmltype;
    v_xml_reason xmltype;
  begin  
    if p_reasons is null then
      throw('Input parameter is empty');
    end if;
    
    v_xml_reasons_in := xmltype(p_reasons);
      
    select xmlelement("Reasons") into v_xml_reasons_out from dual;
       
    select 
      id as reason_id, 
      name as attr_name   
    bulk collect into v_attrs_in 
    from XMLTable('Reasons/Reason' passing (v_xml_reasons_in) 
      columns id number path 'Id',
      attr_list XMLType path 'AttrList/Attr')(+) xt_att,
      XMLTable('Attr' passing (xt_att.attr_list) 
      columns name varchar2(200) path 'Name');

    if v_attrs_in is not empty then
      select
        x.reason_id as reason_id,
        t.attr_name as attr_name,
        a.attr_value as attr_value
      bulk collect into v_attrs
      from table(v_attrs_in) x
      join reason_attrs t on t.attr_name = x.attr_name
      left join reason_attr_value a on a.reason_id = x.reason_id and a.attr_id = t.attr_id  
        and sysdate between a.date_begin and nvl(a.date_end, sysdate + 1);   
   
      if v_attrs is not empty then
        
        select distinct x.reason_id
        bulk collect into v_reason_ids
        from table (v_attrs) x
        where x.attr_value is not null;
        
        if v_reason_ids is not empty then
          for i in v_reason_ids.first..v_reason_ids.last loop
            select xmlelement("Reason",
              xmlforest
              (
                v_reason_ids(i) as "Id",
                xmlagg(xmlelement("Attr", XMLAttributes(x.attr_name as "name"), x.attr_value)) as "AttrList" 
              ))
            into v_xml_reason
            from table (v_attrs) x
            where x.reason_id = v_reason_ids(i);
            
            v_xml_reasons_out := v_xml_reasons_out.appendChildXML('//Reasons',v_xml_reason);         
          end loop;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;

    return v_xml_reasons_out.getClobVal(); 
  end get_reason_attr_value;
```

Description of the collections used in the function:

```sql
type reason is record
  (
    reason_id number,
    attr_name varchar2(200)
  );
  type reason_attr is record
  (
    reason_id number,
    attr_name varchar2(200),
    attr_value varchar2(2000)
  );
  
  type reasons is table of reason;
  type reason_attrs is table of reason_attr;
  type reason_id_list is table of number;
```

Example input XML file (may contain thousands of element `Reason`):

```sql
<Reasons>
  <Reason>
    <Id>3</Id>
    <AttrList>
      <Attr>
        <Name>include_in_recalculation</Name>
      </Attr>
    </AttrList>
  </Reason>
  <Reason>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <AttrList>
      <Attr>
        <Name>include_in_recalculation</Name>
      </Attr>
    </AttrList>
  </Reason>
  <Reasons>
```

Comment: can you provide sample data for p_reasons?

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot, updated text of the question

Comment: привет, why do you need to optimize it? Is it slow or you've been told it needs to be optimized?

Comment: Including your `reason_attr` table, a selection of representative data, and expected output might also be helpful. An explanation of the end goal might be good too. It seems like you are effectively removing attributes which are not valid based on a date in that table, and any reasons that have no valid attributes; is that right?